# Problems with facebook login android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a lot of trouble to implement Facebook's login in my app...

I actually could indeed implement the login and it's working (copying and pasting a code from a tutorial)... but the problem is what I do now.... 
I want to the user to go to the UI of my app after he logs in...
In my mind, the correct way would be to start a new activity after facebook's login where I can pass to the new activity ways to retrieve info from the user's profile and continue to be able to use facebook's sdk features.

My problems start there... I can't find any recent tutorial about facebook's SDK of how to implement this simple kind of app...
I don't know even how to retrieve user's data from the facebook's session.
Facebook's documentation is really confuse and don't explain nothing about it... or if it does I really can't understand it...

It seems like the old SDK was a lot easier to use...

Does anyone know a good tutorial that explains how the new SDK really works?

*I have the login working with Facebook's LoginButton...
*I want to change completely the UI so that the user can indeed use my app right after the login...
*I'm having really trouble to understand how facebook's SDK works

I'm sorry if it's not a really straight forward question, but I can't find help anywhere...

Thanks in advance

Comment: please specify, paste some codes or images for better understanding regarding your problem, or the log for the errors if any.

Answer (score 0):

try this very useful `library` [Simple Facebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook)
 by Roman Kushnarenko.